# How can I make my mouse not leave the rectangle I want?

Tags: mouse, vb.net-2010

So I tried with

```
cursor.Clip = New Rectangle (desired coordinates)
```

But for some reason, it doesn't seem to work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It works on 2 sides (right and bottom), but it doesn't work on the other sides. But not even on the left side it is on the right coordinate, where I set the Rectangle.

How can I work this out?

Comment: The Rectangle() should be in **screen** coords.  Are you properly converting your rectangle values?  What is the rectangle based on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your values for the Rectangle are in **screen** coords.  For example, the following code will clip the cursor to Button2 when Button1 is clicked:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Cursor.Clip = Me.RectangleToScreen(Button2.Bounds) ' confine cursor to the second button
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Cursor.Clip = Nothing ' release the clip
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I had the right rectangle, I filled it with a color and checked if it was right, yet it was not going to work, however with this 'RectangleToScreen' property it works just fine now, thank you.

Comment: "I had the right rectangle, I filled it with a color and checked if it was right" That's because filling the rectangle would also be done in client coords, but Clip() was treating those client coords as screen coords.

Comment: Be aware that in my example, RectangleToScreen() was being called against "Me" since the Form was the container for the Button.  If a different container is used, like a Panel, then you'd use that instead of the Form ("Panel1.RectangleToScreen").  You could also do it using only Button2, without referencing its container at all, like this: `Cursor.Clip = Button2.RectangleToScreen(Button2.ClientRectangle)`